# What's wrong with my Powershell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-7, remote-access

I don't understand this error message I'm receiving when I try to run my powershell script. The purpose is to copy a .bat file into the main win 7 startup folder on a series of machines.

[image]

And the script I am running.

```powershell
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\ServersList.txt" #Change this to location of servers list
$SourceFileLocation = "C:\firefox_issue.bat" #For example: D:\FoldertoCopy\ or D:\file.txt
$Destination = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" #Example: C$\temp

foreach ($_ in $ServerList)
 {Copy-Item $SourceFileLocation -Destination \\$_\$Destination -Recurse -PassThru}


Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")

Write-Host
Write-Host "A"
Write-Host "B"
Write-Host "C"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your location is getting set to:

```
\\SERVERNAME\C:\ProgramData...
```

and it should be:

```
\\SERVERNAME\C$\ProgamData...
```

Your destination needs to be:

```
$Destination = 'C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup'
```

And your loop should be:

```
foreach($server in $serverList) {
  Copy-Item $SourceFileLocation -Destination "\\$server\$Destination" -Recurse
}
```

You should probably avoid explicitly using `$_` as a variable name as `$_` is a special variable for accessing an object in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the comment behind the `$Destination` line? 
This is a UNC path. 
`\\server1\c:\programdata\` is not a valid UNC-path. Try:

```
$Destination = "C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Also, `$_` is a reserved variable for pipeline input, so you need to change it, like:

```
foreach ($server in $ServerList)
 {Copy-Item $SourceFileLocation -Destination \\$server\$Destination -Recurse -PassThru}
```